# Dealing with Arrays in Powershell (testing with Pester)

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, pester

I have a little trouble understanding the way to implement this process. I want to achieve a total count in the score so that if a test successfully passes or fails it can be added into an array. That array will be counted in the length.

This is my code as an example:

```
#This stores the array of the number of passed and failed test
$passed = @()
$failed = @() 

Describe "Template Syntax" {

    It "Has a JSON template" {        
       $fileLocation = "$here\azuredeploy.json" 
       $fileCheck = $fileLocation | Test-Path

        if ($fileCheck -eq $true) {  $passed = $passed + 1
        Write-Host "1st file exist " }
        if ($fileCheck -eq $false) { $failed = $failed + 1
        Write-Host "1st file does exist" }

        }

        It "Has a parameters file" {        
     $fileLocation ="$here\azuredeploy.parameters*.json"

      $fileCheck = $fileLocation | Test-Path

        if ($fileCheck -eq $true) {  $passed = $passed + 1; 
        Write-Host "2nd file exist "}
        if ($fileCheck -eq $false) {  $failed = $failed + 1
        Write-Host "2nd file does exist" }

        } 

        PrintArgs

        }

function PrintArgs(){
Write-Host -ForegroundColor yellow "Passed: $($passed.Length) Failed: $($failed.Length)"
   }
```

Is there a different way or another approach that I can do to achieve this? I know that pester does it automatically, however, I want to use a Powershell script to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Pester tests aren't really Pester tests unless you include a `Should` assertion. I think you should rewrite your tests as follows:

```
Describe "Template Syntax" {
    $fileLocation = "$here\azuredeploy.json" 
    $fileCheck = $fileLocation | Test-Path

    It "Has a JSON template" {        
        $fileCheck | Should -Be $true
    }

    $fileLocation ="$here\azuredeploy.parameters*.json"
    $fileCheck = $fileLocation | Test-Path

    It "Has a parameters file" {        
        $fileCheck | Should -Be $true
    } 
}
```

If you then run this with `Invoke-Pester` you get a summary of passed and failed test counts at the end automatically. If you need to access these values, you can use `-PassThru` to return them to a variable. For example:

```
$Results = Invoke-Pester .\your.tests.ps1 -PassThru
```

Then you can get the number of passed and failed tests as follows:

```
$Results.PassedCount
$Results.FailedCount
```

If you genuinely want to use your own counters (which would mean maintaining lots of unnecessary logic) you could do as follows:

```
$Passed = 0
$Failed = 0

Describe "Template Syntax" {
    $fileLocation = "$here\azuredeploy.json" 
    $fileCheck = $fileLocation | Test-Path

    It "Has a JSON template" {        
        $fileCheck | Should -Be $true
    }

    if ($fileCheck -eq $true) {  $Passed++ } else { $Failed++ }

    $fileLocation ="$here\azuredeploy.parameters*.json"
    $fileCheck = $fileLocation | Test-Path

    It "Has a parameters file" {        
        $fileCheck | Should -Be $true
    } 

    if ($fileCheck -eq $true) {  $Passed++ } else { $Failed++ }

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor yellow "Passed: $Passed Failed: $Failed"
}
```

Note that the `Describe` block acts as a kind of script scope, so you have to print the values of `$Passed` and `$Failed` within the `Describe` to get at the values.

Comment: Thank you so much! really helped alot :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you do not need arrays to count the scores.
Instead of defining `$passed` and `$failed` as arrays, just set them up as integer counters with a starting value of 0

```
$passed = $failed = 0
```

Then **instead of calling** function PrintArgs() you simply do

```
Write-Host -ForegroundColor yellow "Passed: $passed Failed: $failed"
```

By the way, to increment a counter you can simply do `$passed++` instead of `$passed = $passed + 1`

If you DO insist on using arrays you can change the `$passed = $passed + 1` to something like `$passed += $true`. By doing that you add a new element to the array with a value of $true (or whatever you feel is more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you so much for the useful help :) , but i am still having trouble with my output. At the end of my result, i should get Passed = 2, Failed = 0. Although I get Passed=0 and Failed=0. @Theo

Comment: Are you now using simple counters instead of arrays or??

Comment: Yep i have changed it into a counter :) @Theo

Comment: Ah.. Sorry i made a stupid typo. Edited my answer. What i meant was to drop the `printArgs` function and write out the counters straight away. Anyway.. Marks answer is better, but this may have helped in understanding increments and adding elements to arrays I hope.